# Objective - C - NavigationBar Title

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

This is my AppDelegate, i set a title "Pizza", but when i build and play the application, the text don't will appear.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.

UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];
ListaPizzeViewController *listPizzeVC = [[ListaPizzeViewController alloc]init];

UINavigationController *navigationControllerPizza = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:listPizzeVC];
[navigationControllerPizza setTitle:@"Pizza"];
navigationControllerPizza.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"];


  ListIngredientsViewController *listIngredientVC = [[ListIngredientsViewController alloc]init];
UINavigationController *navigationControllerIngradient = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:listIngredientVC];
[navigationControllerIngradient setTitle:@"Ingredient"];
navigationControllerIngradient.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"];

[tabBarController setViewControllers:@[navigationControllerPizza, navigationControllerIngradient]];

[self.window setRootViewController:tabBarController];
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

Why?

Comment: Did you happen to try [listPizzeVC setTitle:@"Pizza"]? But it will change when you will push another VC in navigation controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go into your ListaPizzeViewController, inside the viewDidLoad write

```
self.title = @"Pizze";
```

Answer (score 3):

According to Your Question you can set title of `ListaPizzeViewController` using  object of `ListaPizzeViewController` like Bellow:-

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];
    ListaPizzeViewController *listPizzeVC = [[ListaPizzeViewController alloc]init];

    UINavigationController *navigationControllerPizza = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:listPizzeVC];

    [listPizzeVC setTitle:@"Pizza"]; // Here it is you can set Title of Object of Viewcontroller so set like thin not [navigationControllerPizza setTitle:@"Pizza"];

    navigationControllerPizza.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"];


      ListIngredientsViewController *listIngredientVC = [[ListIngredientsViewController alloc]init];
    UINavigationController *navigationControllerIngradient = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:listIngredientVC];
    [navigationControllerIngradient setTitle:@"Ingredient"];
    navigationControllerIngradient.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"];

    [tabBarController setViewControllers:@[navigationControllerPizza, navigationControllerIngradient]];

    [self.window setRootViewController:tabBarController];
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
    }
```

Comment: i given answer according to question. they can set Title as my answer to. this is totally working

Answer (score 1):

```
self.navigationItem.title=@"pizza";
```

simply call this.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set title in viewWillAppear method.

of **"listPizzeVC"** as

```
self.title=@"Pizza";
```

Answer (score 0):

IT is title is ViewController property so use view controller object and title set I write the code under.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:  (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
 {
     self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

     UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];
     ListaPizzeViewController *listPizzeVC = [[ListaPizzeViewController alloc]init];

     UINavigationController *navigationControllerPizza = [[UINavigationController  alloc]initWithRootViewController:listPizzeVC];
    //[navigationControllerPizza setTitle:@"Pizza"];
    listPizzeVC.title=@"Pizza";
    navigationControllerPizza.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"];


    ListIngredientsViewController *listIngredientVC = [[ListIngredientsViewController alloc]init];
    UINavigationController *navigationControllerIngradient = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:listIngredientVC];
   //[navigationControllerIngradient setTitle:@"Ingredient"];
    listIngredientVC.title=@"Ingredient";
   navigationControllerIngradient.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"];

   [tabBarController setViewControllers:@[navigationControllerPizza, navigationControllerIngradient]];

  [self.window setRootViewController:tabBarController];
  self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
```

}

I hope it is useful too.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should not be in the appDelegate but in a viewcontroller class that inherits from UIViewController and attach this class to your xib or storyboard screen. One viewcontroller per screen. Add your code to the viewDidLoad or create your own methods. When this doesn't work you might wanna try and post your question again. ;).

I recently started iOS development, it helped me to take little steps and create small project that aimed for learning one thing at a time this way you will learn really fast and efficient without too much frustration. Good luck!